# how to create and access sqlite-cursor in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

How do I create a cursor and use it in my iphone application?

I am getting 10000+ records using `select * from tablename`.

But I don't want to load all the records at a time... I know that we can use cursor for this.

I am not able to find any samples related to it.. can any body give any link or sample which explains how to use cursor in sqlite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution :
the sql query is

> **const char *sql = "select * from tablename";**

using

> **sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL)**

we will get the result into selectstmt.

now when ever we want to fetch the row we will call the method

> **sqlite3_step(selectstmt)**

, it will return the next row each time when we call.

Comment: That won't solve the question you asked; what if you want the last 10 of your 10,000 rows?  You'll step and ignore 9,990 times?  If you say so...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` clause of the `SELECT` statement.  For example to get records 30 to 40:

```
SELECT something FROM somewhere ORDER BY somethingelse LIMIT 10 OFFSET 30;
```

Your 'cursor' in this case would be the value 30, which you need to track yourself.

[Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).

Comment: cant't we use cursor like in mysql?

Comment: @user1244311 No, I don't think sqlite3 supports cursors.

Comment: [sqlite cursor](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html#xconnect) check out this once... what is it related to. there is a function like "sqlite3_vtab_cursor"

Comment: @user1244311 Sorry I've never used virtual tables.   It might work, but I cannot help you with it.

Comment: I think to make this work in cases where data might be inserted while you are paginating you'd need some kind of logic to assure that you are continuing where you last left off. E.g., if you use an auto-increment pk you could use and order by on the id and limit where the id is after the last one from your previous window. Since the id is auto-incrementing this should handle deletions as well (since newer rows would be higher). Using an offset wouldn't handle these cases since later windows are shifted in rows are inserted / deleted from before that window.